# Prepopulating HSQL tables

Tags: java, sql, unit-testing, hsqldb

My manager has asked if I can unit test the DAO using HSQL. Never having heard of it I read some and whipped up a little implementation for unit testing with an in memory db. What I found was that, due to foreign keys, it will be hard to test just one function at a time as I would need to make sure the DB had enough info to satisfy the foreign key constraints. Is there a simple way to populate the tables with a base level of information? All the info I keep finding seems to only be fore a clean slate in memory or a standalone instance used as any other db.

**Note:** This isn't stand alone, it is part of a maven managed eclipse project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) - it can give you the ability to do the pre-test stuff you need.